# Enrich angularjs json data with additional view logic properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When I load my json data from the server I need to have additional view only properties on json data. But thats not possible.

Then I thought about creating angularjs models from factories like:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('TGB').factory('TestViewModel', function () {

    function TestViewModel(test) {

        this.id = test.id;
        this.schoolclassCode = test.schoolclassCode;
        this.testType = test.type;
        this.creationDate = test.date;
        this.number = test.number;
        this.isExpanded = false;
    }

    return (TestViewModel);
});
```

Where do you create these viewmodels in angular?

```
At the moment I have this method in my Controller , call it there and assign the result to $scope.testViewModels = toTestListViewModel(tests)

function toTestListViewModel(tests)
    {
        var testListViewModel = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            var testViewModel = new TestViewModel(tests[i]);
            testListViewModel.push(testViewModel);
        } 
        return testListViewModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller is a proper place to create your 'view model' that can be accessed using $scope.

```
.controller('sampleCtrl', function ($scope, testViewModel) {
   $scope.vM = testViewModel;
}
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me. I want to/have to new up the TestViewModel instance by myself passing the test json entity. Where do I have to new up that viewmodel at best? I updated my question too with more info!

Comment: Where is that json coming from? Http response?

Comment: So why not just use $http service in your controller or just add a method on your factory that will call your back end and repopulate your data?

Comment: I use ui router with resolve property. I do not call my $htp service in the controller. I have client side services wrapping $http calls.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ui router framework so can not help you with that. Sorry